# Stack Exchange coming up with a site for Gadgets\Devices

Tags: feature-request

I wish if Stack Exchange could come up with a site specifically for Gadgets and Devices, where people could write reviews discuss issues and also promote their products.

Comment: Stack Exchange sites do not exist for people to promote their products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think a certain StackExchange site should exist, go propose it on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)! (Remember to search to see if one exists already first, thought)

In fact, a StackExchange site on [Electronic Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets) has been tried, but failed its beta, as they didn't get enough traffic. For more information, read the [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/) that was posted about the decision to shut it down.

Comment: Thx for letting me know about Area51. In future definitely I will be looking down here before making feature requests.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see with such sites is that they are argumentative by nature which does not really help to build a Q&A site.